# How to Mock Command Handler to return the success Response Code in Xunit Moq?

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am unit testing in Xunit, using Moq for mocking

I am following CQRS pattern, The class being tested looks like this

```
{
public class command : IRequest<VehicleListingResponse>, IReqTransaction
{
 public string name {get;set;}
 public int numberOfVehicles {get;set}
}

public class Handler : IReqHandler<Command,VehilceListResponse>
{

// list of properties

public Handler() // list of arguments for dependency injection

public async Task<VehicleListResponse> Handle (request,cancel)
{

// API logic

}

}
}
```

**How can I mock the API to return the success status Code of 200?**

Comment: Please provide some [mre]? At least something compilable.

Comment: Why would you need to mock the API, and not simply test the `Handle` method? Every dependency in the class should be mockable.